# Get second word of each line in a textbox to use in a command

Tags: c#, string, winforms, split, textbox

i need to get the secord word from a users input from a TextBox, the textbox contains multiple lines and in each line the second word needs to be used in a commandline argument. i have tried the below but that greps everything and cant handle new line aswell.

any ideas appreciated!

`string secondword = textBox1.Text;`

`string\[\] split = secondword.Split(' ');`

```
            for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
            {
                
                
                Process dmdevicehost1c1 = new Process();
                dmdevicehost1c1.StartInfo.FileName = "plink";
                dmdevicehost1c1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                dmdevicehost1c1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                dmdevicehost1c1.StartInfo.Arguments = "user@<ip address> -batch -pw <password> mmlsnsd |grep datavol |grep" + split;
                dmdevicehost1c1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                dmdevicehost1c1.Start();
                textBox4.AppendText(dmdevicehost1c1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());`
```

[image]

i've attached a picture of the textbox and how the format of it looks.

i basically need it to grep the last word of each line and run the command the same amount of times as there are lines, so one time with the first lines second word, then again with the second lines second word and so forth..

Comment: Check out the [TextBoxBase.Lines Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). This property is what you need; you can go through each line and split where you need to. Pay attention to the example and the remarks section as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, `string[] split = secondword.Split(':');` is just going to return an array containing 1 element which is the whole content of your text box, because the text box doesn't contain any occurrences of the character `:`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char())

Comment: Ohh yes sorry.. tried a bunch of things with the layout of the input so i forgot to put it like this in the thread!
string[] split = secondword.Split(' ');

just edited it! thanks!

Comment: Thanks Trevor, i will look at that!

Answer (score 0):

```
            // Create a string array and store the contents of the Lines property.
            string[] tempArray = textBox1.Lines;
            // Loop through the array and send the contents of the array to debug window.
            for (int counter = 0; counter < tempArray.Length; counter++)
            {
                string[] subs = tempArray[counter].Split(' ');

                MessageBox.Show(subs[1]);

            }
```

That solved it ;) i used a messagebox only to debug, so that it did not send the wrong information to the server ;)

Thanks Trevor for pointing me in the correct direction!